# An interesting question in number theory

Tags: number-theory

Let $ x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n $ be a sequence consecutive of composite integers. Show that $ x_n $ admits a strict divisor $ d $ such that $ d> n $.
Exemple: 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 is a sequence consecutive of composite integers.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. When you post a question it helps if you try to show your line of thought.

Comment: Addressing the question of a sequence of consecutive *composite* integers:

One heuristic argument is that the sequence of prime gaps grows slowly, so by the time you have a sequence of $n$ consecutive composite integers, their absolute values would be quite large compared to $n$. Since the last element of that sequence is composite, it will have some proper divisor at least as large as its square root.

Comment: So it's a question of how good of an upper bound you can get for the prime gaps, like $p_{k+1} - p_k \leq f(k)$, and then a sufficient condition would be showing that $p_{f^{-1}(n+1)} > n^2 - n$, because $f(k) \geq p_{k+1} - p_k \geq x_n - x_1 + 2 = n + 1$. So if $p_k + 1 \leq x_1 \leq x_n \leq p_{k+1} - 1$, that condition would imply that $x_n > n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where $x_k=k$ for $1 \le k \le n.$ This is a sequence of consecutive integers for which $x_n=n.$ But here $x_n$ has only divisors each at most $n$, none $>n.$

Comment: The question might have been modified later, or I might have misunderstood something, but based on what I'm seeing the OP is talking about a sequence of consecutive *composite* integers, which isn't guaranteed in that example.

Comment: @TobErnack Now I see it was modified. But it has been closed anyway. -(